# How to add a new tag in xml file using shell scripting?

Tags: xml, shell

I have an xml file like

```
<changeSet id="1" author="naveen" dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/IntialVersion.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="2" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/FirstRev.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="3" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/23_12_2011.sql" />
    </changeSet>
```

I want to add a new changeSet tag like below using shell scripting

```
 <changeSet id="4" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/24_12_2011.sql" />
    </changeSet>
```

Is there any simple way to do this in shell scripting? I have to change id and sql file name also in the tag.

Comment: `echo '<newtag />' >> file.xml`. It won't be valid, but it's a new tag in the xml file...

Answer (score 1):

Quick, dirty, unreliable. Does not parse XML - this just assumes that your input file will always retain the current line formatting.

cat test.xml

```
<intro>
a\b&c;
d$e
</intro>
<changeSet id="1" author="naveen" dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/IntialVersion.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="2" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/FirstRev.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="3" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/23_12_2011.sql" />
    </changeSet>
<outro>
</outro>
```

Determine the line number of last changeSet tag

```
line_no="`grep -n '</changeSet>$' test.xml | cut -f1 -d: | tail -n 1`" ; echo "$line_no"
```

Add new changeSet

```
[[ -n "$line_no" ]] && sed "$line_no"'s#$#\n<changeSet id="4" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">\n  <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/24_12_2011.sql" />\n</changeSet>#' test.xml > test.xml.new
```

cat test.xml.new

```
<intro>
a\b&c;
d$e
</intro>
<changeSet id="1" author="naveen" dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/IntialVersion.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="2" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/FirstRev.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="3" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
      <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/23_12_2011.sql" />
    </changeSet>
<changeSet id="4" author="naveen"  dbms="oracle">
  <sqlFile path="/appl/Liquibase/sql/24_12_2011.sql" />
</changeSet>
<outro>
</outro>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a well-formed XML file, but if you just want to append to the end of the file, then use `echo` or `cat` command and send its output to the end of the file with `>>` operator.

Comment: I dont want to add it in the last. It is not full xml. It is a part of my full xml file. I want to add this tag right after the previous tag in between the xml file with the use of shell script. any help??

Comment: Can you show your full xml structure? It will be easier to help.